# Get system default package name

Tags: android

How can I know which is the package name of default system app if user has one defined? By example get the package name of system default music app to stop it

Answer (score 1):

solved:

```
String mKillAppName = null;

headsetPlugIntent = Intent.makeMainSelectorActivity(Intent.ACTION_MAIN,
    Intent.CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC);

ResolveInfo da = mContext.getPackageManager()
    .resolveActivity(headsetPlugIntent,PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

mKillAppName = da.activityInfo.packageName;
```